# Value for a variable as a rational number

Tags: quadratics, rational-numbers

Given that $a$ and $b$ are rational numbers and that $x = \frac{\sqrt 5+3}{\sqrt 5+2}$ is the solution for $x^2 + ax + b = 0$

Can I derive the values of a and b from the resulting equation?
$$
-a + b + 6 + (a - 2)√5 = 0
$$

Comment: Can you add a rational number to an irrational number to give a zero resultant sum?

Comment: So $ (a - 2)\sqrt{5} = a - b - 6$. The right hand side is rational for any choice of rational values for $a$ and $b$. The left hand side is irrational for almost all values of $a$, except....

Comment: i see, so in cases like this when i'm looking for rational numbers only i have to get ride of the irrational side of the equation by taking a value of a or b that makes it zero, in this case a=2, is that correct?

Comment: @Scienceboy That's correct. Another way to solve it would be to first rationalize the fraction, and you'll find that $x = \sqrt{5} - 1$. Then the other root must be $-\sqrt{5} -1$ and you calculate $a, b$ using Vieta's.